# How to block multiple requests coming from same IP

Tags: asp.net, ip, firewall

My aim is to block/control multiple requests coming from same IP address using a firewall or router.Can i achieve this programatically? or using some other configuration? Can someone guide me and provide some links that might help my cause.

Thanks

Comment: If you could do this programmatically then the request already went through into your application and the blocking has no sense at all? On the other hand, if you would describe the _reason_ to block, this could make sense...

Comment: I have a c# web application where I need to limit the user from liking a video multiple times. So I need to block that request coming from same user(possibly).

Comment: also few days ago someone hacked my site and caused the site to crash with multiple requests. So it would be helpful if i block multiple requests coming from same IP address.

Comment: I provided an answer below, but based on your comments, I think you're approaching this the complete wrong way. Your application should have code such that an incoming "like" request is checked against a list of previous likes to prevent duplicates from occurring. A single web page may require 15-20 requests from the same IP address just to download all the content. It seems like you do not really have a clear understanding of the problem, and the solution you're asking for is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @Chris: I think I confused myself.I mean DOS attack is the real reason as to why I am looking for a solution so as to block multiple requests from an IP.

Comment: What firewall are you using? Most modern firewalls and content switches offer a service protection mechanism by which you can specify a max number of connections per interval and auto-ban hosts that cross the threshold, either permanently or for a set period of time. You shouldn't have to prevent denial of service at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your application has network access to the server that runs your firewall, and assuming you can run an SSH command to that host, you might be able to run an SSH command to echo a command to the firewall's config file to block an IP. Seems like a very bad idea though. Assuming a linux firewall with iptables, here's some relevant information:

- http://bashcurescancer.com/run_remote_commands_with_ssh.html
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-block-an-ip-on-my-linux-server/
- http://bash.cyberciti.biz/firewall/iptables-block-ip-address/

Comment: I think what you're asking for is rate limiting, which can almost always be done at the firewall level, independent of the application. For an example of how to do this using iptables, see: http://codingfreak.blogspot.com/2010/01/iptables-rate-limit-incoming.html

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically you can do that by capturing all page call on global.asax and log on an array the ip calls. If you get from one ip too many calls at short time like a DOS attack you can cut it.

There are two examples with source code that I know and show you here.

[Prevent Denial of Service (DOS) attacks](http://omaralzabir.com/prevent_denial_of_service__dos__attacks_in_your_web_application/)

and

[Block Dos attacks in asp.net](http://madskristensen.net/post/Block-DoS-attacks-easily-in-ASPNET.aspx)

the last one have an error on the line that stop the comming from indexes, just remove this line.

This examples are a start, you can customize them to your application.