# How to make my site secure from XSS. How to track IP which make thousand of Fake request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing, performance-testing

I have a ActionResult in Asp.net mvc website. it's read a lot of data when request made and show them on page.

Now I thing their is a problem. If the person make ajax request using Firebug and make loop of the request then my server got enough workload.

What I means is suppose I write a loop and make 1000 Fake ajax request then my server have run 1000 time sql queries and all the workload is useless.

how i can track it. Do someone have any help regarding this.

Comment: So what would make a call legitimate ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I thing something can be done with IP. The only thing that I track is IP which will be same at every request !. Any idea

Comment: If it's not a problem for the customers, you could just limit the amount of equal request per IP per second

Answer (score 2):

MVC's Anti-Forgery Token support writes a unique value to an HTTP-only cookie and then the same value is written to the form. When the page is submitted, an error is raised if the cookie value doesn't match the form value.

It's important to note that the feature prevents cross site request forgeries. That is, a form from another site that posts to your site in an attempt to submit hidden content using an authenticated user's credentials. The attack involves tricking the logged in user into submitting a form.

The feature doesn't prevent any other type of data forgery or tampering based attacks.

To use it, decorate the action method or controller with the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute.

I found that information from question answered by Richard Szalay :

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken purpose, explanation and example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621934/could-you-explain-validateantiforgerytoken-purpose-and-show-me-example-about-val)

For blocking multiple requests from same Ip/ DDOS, please check the question's answers:

[How to block multiple requests coming from same IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597039/how-to-block-multiple-requests-coming-from-same-ip)